# POST request - String parameter is not present

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am using AJAX to send data to server. It works if I put all data to URL, so everything is OK. But when I put all data to "data" in AJAX, server writes - required String parameter is not present. Eventhough I can see all data in requests body (in browser). What might be wrong?

```
const data = {
        firstName: name,
        surname: surname,
        email: email,
        password: pass1,
        roles: roles
      };
        state.search.method("POST", "users", JSON.stringify(data));

 method(type_, url_, data_){
        $.ajax({
          url: proxy + url_,
          type: type_,
          contentType: "x-www-form-urlencoded",
          dataType: "json",
          headers: {
            'Authorization': 'bearer ' + localStorage.access_token
          },
          data: data_,
          success: function(result){
              alert("OK METHOD"); 
          },
          error(XMLHttpRequest, textStatus, errorThrown){
            alert('Error: ' + errorThrown + ", " + textStatus);
          console.log(XMLHttpRequest.status + ' ' + 
              XMLHttpRequest.statusText);
          }
        });
      }
```

[image: Response]

Comment: What is your backend language?

Comment: Apparently your server expects the data in the URL, not in the body.

Comment: If the backend is php, then url arguments appear in $_GET while post arguments appear in $_POST, and they both appear in $_REQUEST

Comment: Try changing `type_` to 'GET'

Comment: @charlietfl if the server was configured properly the response should have been a 415 Method Not Supported, not a 400. Although given the context of what the code is doing a GET request does make more sense.

Comment: @Heretic Monkey you are right. I am accepting only parameters from URL at back-end. Thank you :-)

Answer (score 0):

Maybe the server is trying to read information through query string only, which means you should use GET method instead of a POST submission.

Try changing your method() function like this:

```
method(type_, url_, data_){
    $.ajax({
      url: proxy + url_,
      type: "get", //Send using GET method
      headers: {
        'Authorization': 'bearer ' + localStorage.access_token
      },
      data: data_,
      success: function(result){
          alert("OK METHOD"); 
      },
      error(XMLHttpRequest, textStatus, errorThrown){
        alert('Error: ' + errorThrown + ", " + textStatus);
      console.log(XMLHttpRequest.status + ' ' + 
          XMLHttpRequest.statusText);
      }
    });
}
```

And then, you call it **without** the json stringfy like this:

```
state.search.method("POST", "users", data);
```

Answer (score 0):

Can't say i am 100% on this answer but i have assumed 2 things here

That you are actually wanting to perform a 'GET' request here instead of post, as you have said you have tried the URL in the browser and then i assume what you mean is you have keyed this into the address bar then that would be a 'GET' request.

What you can use in JQuery is the $.params function  to build your query. so then your code may look something like this.

Your Data object

```
const data = {
            firstName: 'name',
            surname: 'surname',
            email: 'email',
            password: 'pass1',
            roles: 'roles'
        }
```

Ajax method

```
let queryString = $.param(data)
let url = 'https://your base url';

$.ajax({
   url:url+'?'+queryString, //Building your url for getting the data
   method: 'GET',
   success: function(data){
     console.log(data);
   },
   error: function(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown){
     console.log(textStatus) // You can console.log the other values for debugging
   }
});
```

I think there will be a little work to do to map your values form where you are gettin them into your object and then also into the ajax method.

if you can give me more details about how these are pull together then i can happoly provide an update with more specific information

Hope this helps

*NOTE* if it is a POST of the data just need to understand what the payload would need to be like.

Answer (score 0):

You are posting JSON:

> ```
> state.search.method("POST", "users", JSON.stringify(data));
> ```

You claim you are posting `x-www-form-urlencoded` data

> ```
> contentType: "x-www-form-urlencoded",
> ```

If you are trying to post JSON, then send it with the correct Content-Type: `application/json`

If you are trying to post URL encoded data then:

1. Send it with the correct Content-Type (it's the default for jQuery so omit the `contentType` parameter entirely, or get it correct (`application/x-www-form-urlencoded`).
2. Send data in that format: `state.search.method("POST", "users", data);` (jQuery will encode an object in that format by default).

> It works if I put all data to URL

If you want to post all the data in the URL, then you should be making a GET request and encoding it properly.

So:

Specify **GET** and, again, pass an object not a sting of JSON: `state.search.method("GET", "users", data);` (and jQuery will properly encode the data in the query string).